# How to clean database without stopping tomcat using java

Tags: java, sql-server-2005, tomcat

I am using sql server and tomcat for my web application
To refresh/clean my database i have to close tomcat for successful cleanup
Is there any way using java that i can clean my database without closing tomcat

Comment: My web application uses tomcat server for hosting and sql server for database connections, I am designing a selenium based automation suite to test my web application which should be able to perform database cleanup in between. My problem is that once tomcat is running i am not able to perform sql queries on database, to perform it i have to shutdown tomcat server, So i am asking is there any way to perform sql queries without stopping tomcat

Comment: What does "not able to perform sql queries" mean? Could you describe "database cleanup" better?

Comment: in my case database cleanup means deleting all data from your database. When you create a new database it is blank and only contains tables. Cleanup is deleting all data user had added to database after its creation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can kill external connections to your database using:

```
USE master;
GO
ALTER DATABASE dbname SET SINGLE_USER WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE;
GO
USE dbname;
GO
-- now you can perform your "database cleanup" as you are the only
-- user allowed in.
```

When you are done your cleanup:

```
USE master;
GO
ALTER DATABASE dbname SET MULTI_USER;
GO
```

Now, what happens to the users who try to access the application during this time, and how tomcat reacts, *<shrug>*. Seems a lot cleaner to just shut tomcat down, depending on what you want the users to see during cleanup.

Comment: ok thanks will try this and no user will access tomcat during cleanup

Comment: great it worked except don't use the last line USE dbname; as i am doing this from java if i use this command use DBNAME then i will not be able to execute queries on this database as we are using it and single user is allowed only. Remove use dbname and it worked perfect

Comment: That was so that you could run your script *in that window*... any delay in getting sole access to the database could mean that someone or something else (e.g. SQL Server Agent) could take your only connection before you do. If you're running the script outside of Management Studio, then yes, I agree, don't take that connection yourself.

Comment: thanks for the answer, ya i understand why we do not need use dbname

Answer (score 0):

You can execute SQL commands from your java code like DELETE and DROP TABLE

Comment: thanks for your answer but i already have sql queries to perform database cleanup but my problem is different. Please read my comments above

Answer (score 0):

You must close all database connections that your tomcat webapps have held open.

To do this without stopping tomcat, you have to somehow tell your webapps to either temporarily shutdown their db connections while the database is being refreshed (too much hassle) or just simply shutdown the webapps that use database connections by removing them from the webapps folder.

A combination of the two techniques would be best: signal to your webapps to shutdown, then kill them.

Comment: My web application is deployed in web apps folder if i delete it how can i access it after clean up, i am designing a automation sute to test my web application and perform database cleanup in between and if i delete webapps folder how can i access w=my web application after database cleanup

Comment: Just put the `war` file (or whatever your deployment packaging is) back in webapps when you're done - the app will come back up.